# Flutter: widget not aligning to bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface, frontend, whitespace

I have a widget that for whatever reason does not want to go to the bottom of the screen. Right now the screen looks like:

```
body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                      Column(
                    children: [
                      //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 20,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.imageUrls[0]),
                            ),
                            //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 16,
                            ),
                            //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLength: 280,
                                controller: _textEditingController,
                                maxLines: null,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'What\'s happening?',
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                      if (_image != null)
                        Image.file(
                          _image!,
                          height: 200,
                          width: 200,
                        ),

                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: ComposeBottomIconWidget(
                          onImageIconSelected: _onImageIconSelected,
                          textEditingController: _textEditingController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Which results in:

[image]

Any idea why this is looking like this? The widget is wrapped in an alignment, but still does not change. Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use spacer() to make space between them.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap SingleChildScrollView in Expanded